# Android - Open Folder in Gallery

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-gallery

I've been reading a lot of answers on SO about opening a specific folder inside the System gallery app but none of them solved my problem.

What I need:

When a user clicks on a button I want to open the gallery app inside a **specific folder** (ex: /sdcard/DCIM/MyApp_Downloads/) like below:

[image]

And **NOT** this ( where I still need to choose a folder - album -):

[image]

Comment: Instead of just down voting, please explain why.

Comment: thats the nasty one , form Tuga's side

Comment: It's easier to close the question than posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think currently there is no this kind of Intent Action provided by Samsung. No Gallery docs exist actually. Even if Samsung makes some change later, normally you won't know how to use some specific intent, unless you can get Samsung's source code.

Comment: Is there any intent just to open a folder? it doesn't need to be on samsung devices.

Comment: I suppose no. Because Samsung's Gallery is based on Google's open source gallery. The intent has to be supported by Gallery. Unless you modify the system gallery.

Comment: That's a hard pill to swallow.